# Bauhn tablet Bluetooth keyboard not working

Tags: external-keyboard

My Bauhn tablet runs ICS. It will pair with my Bluetooth keyboard but doesn't actually type anything. I've tested by connecting to my Samsung Galaxy S 3 phone, and the keyboard works fine. But it won't work on the Bauhn.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to download the app [BlueInput](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teksoftco.android.blueinput). Bit of a pain but will allow you to use the keyboard.